# Define trajectory of edge in Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I am trying to draw some Feynman diagrams using TikZ and I am having some trouble defining the trajectory some edges take. The code below might be a bit clunky, but it delivers the diagram I want, but in a way that makes it not very clear:

[image]

I'd like to draw this diagram in a way that the edges do not cross each other, that is something like
[image]
How can I define the trajectory of the edges to achieve something like that? Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),scale=0.3]
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (a) at (-2,-2) {};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (b) at (-2,2) {};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (c) at (2,-2) {};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (d) at (2,2) {};
        \node[draw,circle,scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};

        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (f) at (3,-2) {};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (g) at (3,2) {};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (h) at (7,-2) {};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=black, scale=0.01] (i) at (7,2) {};
        \node[draw,circle,scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
    \end{feynman}
        \diagram* {
        \draw[-] (a) to node[above,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (e);
        \draw[-] (b) to node[below,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (e);
        \draw[-] (c) to node[above,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (e);
        \draw[-] (d) to node[below,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (e);
        \draw[-] (f) to node[above,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (j);
        \draw[-] (g) to node[below,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (j);
        \draw[-] (h) to node[above,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (j);
        \draw[-] (i) to node[below,midway,sloped, align=center]{\tiny $m$} (j);

        
      };
      \draw[-] (b) to[out=45,in=-135] (f);
      \draw[-] (d) to[out=45,in=-45] (h);
      \draw[-] (a) to[out=-45,in=135] (g);
      \draw[-] (c) to[out=-45,in=135] (i);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, and you can do this with Tikz alone, which you can use within the tikz-based Feynman package:

- define `/.style`s for placing the "m"s via in-path-nodes
- draw 2 `\node`s with `circle`s, using `radius`
- draw the 8 arms

As you can see, I:

- used polar coordinates to define the arms ends
- I stored those end positions as `coordinate`s A1 .. B4
- for node `(j)` (shifted) I had to tell Tikz to use realtive coordinates (`++`)
- I put a node for text `m` AFTER the paths starting-point, using said styles `na`, `nb`, placing the text above or below the arms, as needed

```
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
...        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
```

For the connectors you have different options. One is defining a set of intermediate points via `\coordinate (X) at (..);`, just like nodes and connect like you did.

The alternative I chose, mainly to demonstrate its capability, is using bezier curves, which Tikz does via `.. controls (x,y) and (X,Y) ..`, replacing syntactically `--`.

These are described in the [pgfmanual (showing bezier)](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.4), but here's a bit more from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), section higher order curves:

[image: cubic bezier]

So, the Tikz `controls` statement defines P1 and P2 from aboves animation, where I chose again polar coordinates, and left the green one for you (the red curve tried to start as tangents to the arms, while the others don't). Though it's fairly easy to create those curves now as needed, the downside is that you probably need to clip the resulting image, as it seems to try including thos points P1 and P2.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        nb/.style={sloped,below},       
        na/.style={sloped,above},       
    ]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm}] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm}] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[red]   (A1) .. controls ++(45:10) and ++(-45:5) .. (B3);
        \draw[blue]  (A2) .. controls ++(45:20) and ++(-45:15) .. (B4);
        \draw[green] (A3) -- (B1);
        \draw        (A4)  .. controls ++(-40:5) and ++(135:1) .. (B2);
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**P.S.**: To introduce clipping add as very first statement, i.e. before starting with the circles, see *2.11 Clipping a Path* in the Tikz/pgfmanual:

```
        \clip (-2,-4) rectangle +(13,10);
```

[image: clipped]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was just what I was exactly what I was looking for. As a follow up question, I want to put several pictures like that in an equation, something like: "img1+img2=a", but when doing that the first image in the equation is compiled as text, whereas the other images are fine, do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: Thank you. I suggest to post your follow up question as a new one, where you can also provide more background. If suitable, just link to this question for reference.

Comment: I'll play around a bit more and post the follow up question if needed as you suggested, thanks again.