# TikZ images inside equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, tikz-styles

I am trying to write an equation that involves a sum of Feynman diagrams, that is an equation that looks like "img1+img2+...=a", where each of the images are diagrams like the one in my previous question ([Define trajectory of edge in Tikz figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698030/define-trajectory-of-edge-in-tikz-figure/698040?noredirect=1#698040)). When I compile the equation the first diagramm appears as text and the other ones are fine, how can I solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    a=\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)},nb/.style={sloped,below},na/.style={sloped,above},scale=0.3]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);

        %\draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (45:4) coordinate (D1);
        %\draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(135:3) coordinate (D2);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (A1) .. controls ++(90:1) and ++(90:1) .. (B2);
        \draw (A2) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B1);
        \draw (A3) .. controls ++(-90:1) and ++(-90:1) .. (B4);
        \draw (A4)  .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)},nb/.style={sloped,below},na/.style={sloped,above},scale=0.3]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);

        %\draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (45:4) coordinate (D1);
        %\draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(135:3) coordinate (D2);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (A1) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B1);
        \draw (A2) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B2);
        \draw (A3) .. controls ++(-90:1) and ++(-90:1) .. (B4);
        \draw (A4)  .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)},nb/.style={sloped,below},na/.style={sloped,above},scale=0.3]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);

        %\draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (45:4) coordinate (D1);
        %\draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(135:3) coordinate (D2);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (A1) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B1);
        \draw (A2) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B2);
        \draw (A3) .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B3);
        \draw (A4)  .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is how the output looks for me:
[image]

The text at the beginning is the code for the first diagram and it compiles as is instead of showing the actual diagram.
I have tried the suggestions in the comments, but it has not worked out yet. What I just noticed is that if I write the equation between $$ signs instead of the equation environment it does work out and all diagrams get displayed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\begin{document}

$\langle\mathcal{O}_1(x)\mathcal{O}_1(0)\rangle=&\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)},nb/.style={sloped,below},na/.style={sloped,above},scale=0.3]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);

        %\draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (45:4) coordinate (D1);
        %\draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(135:3) coordinate (D2);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (A1) .. controls ++(90:1) and ++(90:1) .. (B2);
        \draw (A2) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B1);
        \draw (A3) .. controls ++(-90:1) and ++(-90:1) .. (B4);
        \draw (A4)  .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)},nb/.style={sloped,below},na/.style={sloped,above},scale=0.3]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);

        %\draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (45:4) coordinate (D1);
        %\draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(135:3) coordinate (D2);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (A1) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B1);
        \draw (A2) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B2);
        \draw (A3) .. controls ++(-90:1) and ++(-90:1) .. (B4);
        \draw (A4)  .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)},nb/.style={sloped,below},na/.style={sloped,above},scale=0.3]
        % ~~~ circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (e) at (0,0) {$x$};
        \node[draw,circle={radius=13mm},scale=0.7] (j) at (5,0) {$0$};
        
        % ~~~ arms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (  45:2) coordinate (A1);
        \draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ( 135:2) coordinate (A2);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ( -45:2) coordinate (A3);
        \draw (e) -- node[na] {\tiny m} (-135:2) coordinate (A4);
        
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(  45:2) coordinate (B1);
        \draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++( 135:2) coordinate (B2);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++( -45:2) coordinate (B3);
        \draw (j) -- node[na] {\tiny m} ++(-135:2) coordinate (B4);

        %\draw (e) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} (45:4) coordinate (D1);
        %\draw (j) -- node[nb] {\tiny m} ++(135:3) coordinate (D2);
        
        % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (A1) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B1);
        \draw (A2) .. controls ++(90:3) and ++(90:3) .. (B2);
        \draw (A3) .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B3);
        \draw (A4)  .. controls ++(-90:3) and ++(-90:3) .. (B4);
\end{tikzpicture}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. Can you please add a screenshot, as it doesn't compile for me, which seems to be related to `... baseline={(0, 1cm-\MathAxis pt)} ...`. Thank you

Comment: Done. I added the baseline term so that all the diagrams were aligned, as some of them would appear slightly above or below the others.

Comment: When I add the missing `\newcommand{\MathAxis}{30}` it works fine for me.

Comment: I would just use `baseline=(e.base)` to align the diagrams vertically.

Comment: You get the first diagram as well? I just tried adding that and it didn't change it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If instead of your `tikzpicture` options in document preamble define

```
\tikzset{T/.style = {baseline = -0.5ex,
        nb/.style={sloped,below, font=\tiny},
        na/.style={sloped,above, font=\tiny},
        scale=0.3}
        }
```

and to `tikzpicture` add option `[T]` than your MWE compiled with `luaLaTeX` produce:

(no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes)

[image]

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thank you.